# Cake php how to update AROS

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

I have imported the data of users from the CSV file. Now when I try to update user then it is giving me following error

```
AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified by "Array ( [Aro0.model] => User [Aro0.foreign_key] => 292 ) "
```

The reason is I have imported the data from the CSV file in user but my AROS is not updated.

I have updated the ACO with the following command line `"cake AclExtras.AclExtras aco_sync"`.

Can anyone tell how to update my AROS table with new user id generated from CSV import.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to update your AROs:

1. Attach the AclBehavior to the User model and write a method that will save the CSV data using the User model's save method.

   ```
   // In User Model:
   public $actsAs = array(
     'Acl' => array(
       'type' => 'requester'
   );

   // In your importCSV() method assuming in your UsersController:
      $this->User->saveMany($users);
   ```
2. If you have directly imported user data into your DB not using the Model::save() mehthod, use the acl shell via command line to enter AROs.

   cake acl create aro parent_ARO User.user_id

To understand the above syntax, just type `cake acl create`.
You would have to run the above command with all the user_ids that you have added.

**Update:**

3. You can make a shell script that finds all the new users and can use the Model::create() and Model::save() method on the ARO Model as below:

Create a file: app/Console/Command/AclGenShell.php.

```
class AclGenShell extends AppShell {
    public $uses = array('User', 'Aro');

    public function main() {
        $users = $this->User->find('all');
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $this->Aro->create();
            $this->Aro->save(array(
               'model' => 'User',
               'foreign_key' => $user['User']['id'],
               'parent' => 'parent_ARO_alias'
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

Then run:
`cake acl_gen`

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. Second option is working for me. But, is there any way that I can update it with 1 click. Right now I can do by adding  it individually "cake acl create aro Group.1 User.292". I have list of 300 user so I have to do it 300 times right ?

Comment: Thanks Jimmy it works great for me. I saved my time. Thanks again

Comment: i am working multiple data base  i have one main data base if  super admin add user then create  new database and i am implemented acl with new user when i edit user the aro table left right node become zero please any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [ACL Plugin](http://www.alaxos.net/blaxos/pages/view/plugin_acl_2.0).
It helps to create both AROs and ACOs.